# Stored Procedure | Check for IF Exists using Joins in 3 tables and update

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, join

I have a scenario where I have to update my table3 with data from 2 other tables on need basis

Table 1 - **plan_info** : Socurce table 1.Has an ID

Table 2 - **estimates_info**  : Source table 2. Has an ID same as Table1

Table 3 - **admin_info** : Data from joining Table1 and Table2 linking with the ID’s. Typically this table is a result of joining the Table1 and Table2 with their respective ID’s. Table 3 will have ID’s as Table1 & 2

I have to write a stored procedure to check :

If there is a matching Row for each ID of Table2 in Table 3 I do not have to do any action, Else Table 3 has to be inserted with the excess ID’s present in Table2 and it should not overwrite the previous records present.

I have jotted down the below query and it is not working.

```
IF EXISTS ( select * from  estimates_info x , admin_info y where x.ID = y.ID)
BEGIN
--Display all the records
select * from admin_info
END
ELSE
BEGIN
 --insert new record
INSERT INTO admin_info ( 
ID, 
Name,
StartDate, 
AdminFlagged ) 
select a.ID,a.Name, b.StartDate,0
from plan_info a,
estimates_info b
where a.ID = b.ID and  b.StartDate < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0,   GETDATE()), 1)
END
```

Will be of great help if anyone can help me with a breakthrough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this way

```
    If Object_Id('tempdb.dbo.#estimates_info') Is Not Null
Begin
    Drop Table #estimates_info;
End

If Object_Id('tempdb.dbo.#admin_info') Is Not Null
Begin
    Drop Table #admin_info;
End

If Object_Id('tempdb.dbo.#estimates_info') Is Null
Begin
    Create Table #estimates_info
    (
         Id         Int 
        ,Name       Varchar(100)
    )
End

If Object_Id('tempdb.dbo.#admin_info') Is Null
Begin
    Create Table #admin_info
    (
         Id         Int 
        ,Name       Varchar(100)
    )
End


Insert Into #estimates_info(Id, Name) Values
 (1,'ABC')
,(2,'XYZ')
,(3,'PQR');

Insert Into #admin_info(Id, Name) Values
 (1,'ABC')
,(3,'PQR');


If Exists(  Select  1
            From    (
                        Select   Count(x.Id) As xCount
                                ,Sum(Case When y.Id Is Not Null Then 1 Else 0 End) As yCount
                        From    #estimates_info As x With (Nolock)
                                Left Join #admin_info As y With (Nolock) On x.Id = y.Id
                    ) As t
            Where   t.xCount = t.yCount
        )
Begin
    ---- select * from table
End
Else
Begin   
    ---- your insert code
End
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm a lil confused in the part of the code where we are inserting values in the temp table #estimates_info(Id, Name), where as in my scenario; the data will already be present in my table and this data if it is not present in the "admin_info"  table then "admin_info" table has to be updated with those additional rows. Hope I was able to put my thoughts across.

Comment: Here, i was inserted dummy data to just make you understand how to make a join of table 2 and table 3 and check existance when count of total rows of table 2 and after join take sum ( 1 increment to the row ) when id of table 2 exactly mached with table 3, as i applied left join, and if matched found then take 1 for that row and applied Sum finally.

So when count of table 2 equals to Sum of table 3, means you need to do nothing ( in first if block), otherwise in else block, you need to perform insert operation.

Comment: Oh.Ok. Thanks for the detailed explanation. Will work it out.